# Floor simplification using assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I don't understand why *Mathematica* doesn't simplify these expressions:

```
$Assumptions = Element[x,Integers] && x>=0;
Floor[x]
Floor[9/10 + x]
```

The ouput is:

> ```
> Floor[x]
>
> Floor[9/10+x]
> ```

And I would like it to use the assumption and return:

> ```
> x
>
> x
> ```

Comment: [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) is only used by functions that use the option [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html). `Floor` does not have any options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this works when you use `FullSimplify`:

```
FullSimplify[Floor[9/10 + x], Element[x, Integers]]
```

Btw, as soon as you use `$Assumptions` you don't need to specify them and you can simply call `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`.